# thumbnail function get error after one interation

Tags: python-imaging-library

working on a program to resize a gif, after the first cycle the program crash

```
from PIL import Image
from icecream import ic

def process_gif(in_path, out_path= 'out.gif', size= (32,32)):
    with Image.open(in_path) as im :
        images = []
        durations = []
        for i in range(im.n_frames) :
            im.seek(i)
            ic(im.size)
            im.load()
            im.thumbnail(size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS) # noqa
            ic(im.size)
            im.convert('RGBA')
            im_temp = Image.new('RGBA', im.size, (0, 0, 0, 0))
            im_temp.paste(im, (0, 0))
            images.append(im_temp)
            ic(im_temp.size)
            durations.append(im.info['duration'])
        images[0].save(
            out_path,
            interlace=True,
            save_all=True,
            append_images=images[1 :],
            loop=0,
            duration=durations,
            disposal=2,
            background=255,
            optimize=False
        )
```

this is the console print out, as we can see it resize the first photogram with no problem, but at the second iteration it raise an error

```
ic| im.size: (111, 128)
ic| im.size: (28, 32)
ic| im_temp.size: (28, 32)
ic| im.size: (111, 128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\get_emoji\image\process_gift_1.py", line 35, in <module>
    process_gif('571097748154089472.gif')
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\get_emoji\image\process_gift_1.py", line 12, in process_gif
    im.thumbnail(size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS) # noqa
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2538, in thumbnail
    im = self.resize(size, resample, box=box, reducing_gap=reducing_gap)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2093, in resize
    im = im.resize(size, resample, box)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2115, in resize
    return self._new(self.im.resize(size, resample, box))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: box can't exceed original image size
```

I have no idea on how to solve this, theoreticly it should cycle all the photogram, i know for fact that the error are caused by thumbnail because if i remove it the program can reassemble the original gif

Answer (score 0):

```
    for i in range(im.n_frames) :
        im.seek(i)
        im.convert('RGBA')
        im_temp = Image.new('RGBA', im.size, (0, 0, 0, 0))
        im_temp.paste(im, (0, 0))
        im_temp.thumbnail(size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        images.append(im_temp)
```

doing this way resolve the problem, i think im.size pick the first frame of the gif i transformed so the size didn't match the actual size of the consecutive frame, but the size of the processed frame, in fact doing

```
    for i in range(im.n_frames - 1, 0, -1):
        im.seek(i)
        im.thumbnail(size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        im.convert('RGBA')
        im_temp = Image.new('RGBA', im.size, (0, 0, 0, 0))
        im_temp.paste(im, (0, 0))
        images.append(im_temp)
```

also works fine